# create vs new in object creation with TclOO

Tags: tcl

I am looking into `TclOO` and found that we can use `create` or `new` for object creation. 
With `create` we can provide customized name, whereas with `new`, it is computer generated.

```
#!/bin/bash
#\
exec tclsh8.6 $0 $@

::oo::class create calc {
        method add { a b } {
                return [ expr {$a+$b} ]
        }
}

calc create c;
set t [ calc new ]

# Both serves the same purpose here
puts [ c add 3 4 ] 
puts [ $t  add 1 2 ]
```

Is it only about object naming convenience provided by compiler to developer? Also, what can be the scenario where I should prefer `new` instead of `create` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference between `new` and `create` is *exactly* that `create` lets you give the name to use, and `new` makes a fresh one for you. Some kinds of objects (specifically classes) conceal their `new` method so that you are strongly encouraged to only make named instances — given how people use classes, that makes a lot of sense in practice — but it's just concealment and you can override that if you want:

```
oo::define oo::class {
    export new
}
```

Use `new` when you don't care about the name and just want it to be different from everything else. That's the basic rule-of-thumb.

### Singletons

It's also perfect to use `create` to make instances where other OO systems might use singletons. What's more unique than giving them a nice unique name that you control.

### Lifespan management

The main scenario I'm aware of otherwise where using `create` is much more useful is when you want to bound the lifespan of an object to another. In that case, creating the object within the context of another will put the object handle in the container's namespace, and will automatically trigger a delete on the deletion of the container:

```
oo::class create InsideThing {
    constructor {} {
        puts "Made a [self] that is an InsideThing"
    }
    destructor {
        puts "Deleted a [self] that is an InsideThing"
    }
}
oo::class create Container {
    constructor {} {
        puts "Created a [self] that is a Container"
        InsideThing create inner1
        InsideThing create inner2
    }
    destructor {
        puts "Deleted a [self] that is a Container"
    }
}

set c [Container new]
puts "Do stuff..."
$c destroy
```

If you run that code, you get this:

```
Created a ::oo::Obj13 that is a Container
Made a ::oo::Obj13::inner1 that is an InsideThing
Made a ::oo::Obj13::inner2 that is an InsideThing
Do stuff...
Deleted a ::oo::Obj13 that is a Container
Deleted a ::oo::Obj13::inner1 that is an InsideThing
Deleted a ::oo::Obj13::inner2 that is an InsideThing
```

This technique is widely used in TDBC to manage result sets and statements within the context of their containers (statements and connections, respectively).

### Tk Megawidgets

Finally, if you are creating Tk megawidgets using TclOO, you will *definitely* be using `create` but in overridden form, as Tk widgets *must* have unqualified names that start with a `.` and which have a specific embodied hierarchy, and megawidgets are *very* strongly advised to follow the same pattern. Because the name matters a lot in this situation, `new` is the wrong method; it is better to start from `create`. Tk 8.6 has some support classes (not publicly described, but used internally for some dialogs) that makes this sort of thing easier: `tk::Megawidget` and `tk::MegawidgetClass`. Check out [`megawidget.tcl`](http://core.tcl.tk/tk/artifact/9c7a1cbdb143d4b4f4528956cfccc727ee2e258c) in a Tk 8.6 distribution for details.

Comment: Thanks Donal. Really helpful and it's fun too to get the explanation from the creator itself.